# C access 2 dimensional array from function with MAX_SIZE

Tags: c

I write this function but when I print the array a get incorrect numbers:
the problem is because the MAX_SIZE, how can I solve this without change MAX_SIZE?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int MAX_SIZE = 3;


void print(int arr[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE],int n) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[][2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}; 
    print(arr,2); // 1 2 5 0
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You should use "#define MAX_SIZE 3" to define constants in C.

Comment: `void print(int n, int arr[n][n])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare constants in C like:

```
#define MAX_SIZE <value>
```

Your problem will be solved if you set `MAX_SIZE` to `2` since you're trying to access `arr[][2]` not `arr[][3]`.

Correct syntax:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 2
```

#### Output:

```
1 2 4 5
```

That's it.

Comment: can I use other MAX_SIZE? I want to be able to use this function with other size arrays options

Comment: DIY. If you change the value of MAX_SIZE, you must configure the **int arr[][]** of main(). In your current situation, MAX_SIZE must be 2.